# A fair coin is flipped 6 times. Given there are exactly 3 H's, what is the probability that the first is H and the second is T?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A fair coin is flipped $6$ times. Given there are exactly $3$ H's, what is the probability that the first is H and the second is T?

I am very lost - how should I do this question? I would like to know if conditional probability should be used when calculating the chance of the second flip resulting in T.

I guess the "simple" way of doing this (which is not sitting well with my intuition) is just to calculate $0.5^2 = 0.25$.

Comment: You have six slots into which you randomly place $3$ objects (at most one object per slot).  What's the probability that an object goes into the first slot but not the second?

Comment: The denominator is the probability of getting exactly three heads in six tosses.  For the numerator, if the first toss results in heads and the second results in tails, then you can only get exactly three heads in six tosses if exactly two of the last four tosses are heads.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of outcomes with $3$ heads and $3$ tails is $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$

The number of outcomes with the first one being a head and the second one being a tail, can be obtained by the calculating the number of outcomes of the remaining four coin tosses that gives two heads and two tails, which is $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$

Hence the probability is $$\frac{\frac{4!}{2!2!}}{\frac{6!}{3!3!}}=\frac3{10}$$